# jquery 1.10 and makes toggle event run automatically

Tags: jquery, toggle

i'm having a simple code to click a button and toggle div size and color using jquery animate color but the problem is the toggle event happens without clicking and the buttons disappear

html :

```
<input type="button" id="togglemove" value="toggle div1 move" />

<input type="button" id="toggle" value="toggle" /> 

<div class="div1"></div>
```

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("#toggle").toggle(click1,click2);
$("#togglemove").toggle(move1,move2);
    });

function move1(){
    $(".div1").animate({"left":"200px"},1000);
}

function move2(){
    $(".div1").animate({"left":"100px"},1000);
}
function click1(){
    $("div.div1").animate({"width":"400px","border-radius":"10px",'background-color': '#400101','left':'200px'},1000);
}
function click2(){
    $("div.div1").animate({"width":"200px","border-radius":"0",'background-color': '#000000','left':'100px'},1000);
}
```

live on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kaNP4/

Comment: The two `toggle` functions that you have defined in your `ready` function will be executed when your `document` is ready.

Comment: it doesn't even show the buttons for me on Chrome. not toggling either

Comment: moving to 1.83 jquery makes it work http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/jAhvL/ the `.toggle()` function was removed since 1.9 that's why it messes everything up. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thanks all here it's working with jquery 1.10 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytG9N/ i didn't that toggle has been removed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This particular use of toggle was [removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) version, so you need to implement the toggle functionality yourself. A sample implementation is given below

See

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        var state = $(this).data('toggleState');
        if(state){
            click2();
        } else {
            click1();
        }
        $(this).data('toggleState', !state);
    });
    $("#togglemove").click(function(){
        var state = $(this).data('toggleState');
        if(state){
            move2();
        } else {
            move1();
        }
        $(this).data('toggleState', !state);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytG9N/)

Comment: This is not a constructive answer.

Comment: @Andri the question seems to be why it was not working now and nobody else covered this in their answer

Comment: No sorry: "...but the problem is the toggle event happens without clicking and the buttons disappear"

Comment: Much better, even better than my example ;)  1 up

Comment: @jqbeginner  you can have a much more cleaner implementation like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytG9N/2/

Comment: great,  @Arun P Johny and here's my other way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/2rSJm/

Comment: You Sir are awesome! I'm just learning jQuery and this had me stuck for two days! I had no idea the toggle function had been removed. Thanks so much for clearing this up!

Comment: @Arun P Johny Thank you very much. Your answer does help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a listener for a click-event. Maybe your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#toggle").click(function(){
   if($(this).attr("class") != "bigger"){
      click1();
      $(this).addClass("bigger");
   } else {
      click2();
      $(this).removeClass("bigger");
   }
});

$("#togglemove").click(function(){
   if($(this).attr("class") != "bigger"){
      move1();
      $(this).addClass("bigger");
   } else {
      move2();
      $(this).removeClass("bigger");
   }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it was working with jquery 1.8 without the click event

Comment: I'm sorry i just saw that my code is not exactly what you where looking for... i will edit it. But i don't think that this could have worked the way you want it to in jq 1.8. The document.ready-listener has nothing to do with a mouseclick

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Fixed it

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your script to make it work like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kaNP4/9/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="togglemove" value="toggle div1 move" onclick="buttonClicked()" />

<input type="button" id="toggle" value="toggle" onclick="buttonClicked2()"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function buttonClicked() {
    $("#togglemove").toggle(move1,move2);
}

function buttonClicked2() {
    $("#toggle").toggle(click1,click2);
}

function move1(){
    $(".div1").animate({"left":"200px"},1000);
}

function move2(){
    $(".div1").animate({"left":"100px"},1000);
}

function click1(){
    $("div.div1").animate({"width":"400px","border-radius":"10px",'background-color': '#400101','left':'200px'},1000);
}

function click2(){
    $("div.div1").animate({"width":"200px","border-radius":"0",'background-color': '#000000','left':'100px'},1000);
}
```